# Batch file inexplicably displays list of variables

Tags: batch-file

I dont know what I did wrong here, but I get a lot of variable values for some reason

```
@echo off
if not exist gamedata mkdir gamedata
cd gamedata
if not exist batbox.exe cd .. && move batbox.exe gamedata
cd gamedata
if not exist pclass.gm echo. 2> pclass.gm
if not exist playername.gm echo. 2> playername.gm
if not exist username.gm echo. 2> username.gm
if not exist password.gm echo. 2> password.gm
if not exist class.gm echo. 2> class.gm
if not exist weapons mkdir weapons
cd weapons
if not exist wand.gm echo Wand> wand.gm
if not exist sword.gm echo Sword> sword.gm
cd..
if not exist classes mkdir classes
cd classes
if not exist mage.gm echo Mage> mage.gm
if not exist worrior.gm echo Worrior> worrior.gm
cd..
goto vars

:vars
set health=100
set strength=1
set /a rndm=%random% %%15 +1
set /p pclass=<class.gm
cd weapons
set /p wand=<wand.gm
set /p sword=<sword.gm
cd..
cd classes
set /p mage=<mage.gm
set /p worrior=<worrior.gm
cd ..
cd ..
goto menu

:menu
set /p pclass=<pclass.gm
set /p name=<playername.gm
cd gamedata
color 0f
title menu
cls
echo Welcome! What would you like to do?
echo.
echo 1) Login to existing account
echo 2) Create new account
echo 3) Exit the game
set /p menu=: 

if "%menu%" == "1" goto game
if "%menu%" == "2" goto newuser

:login
mode con: cols=50 lines=20
color 0f
cls
title Login
set /p user=<username.gm
set /p pass=<password.gm
echo ======================LOGIN======================
set /p login=Username : 

if %login% == %user% goto password
goto login
:password
cls
echo ======================LOGIN======================
set /p passw=Password : 

if %passw% == %pass% goto game && title GAME
goto password

:newuser
cd gamedata
cls
batbox /c 0x80 /d "%date% %time%"
batbox /g 0 1
echo Make a user:
batbox /g 0 5 /d "Password: "
batbox /g 0 3
set /p user=Username: 

echo %user%> username.gm
goto newpass

:newpass
color 0f
cd gamedata
cls
batbox /c 0x80 /d "%date% %time%"
batbox /g 0 1
echo Make a user:
batbox /g 0 3 /d "Username: %user%"
batbox /g 0 5
set /p pass=Password: 

echo %pass%> password.gm
goto charectarselect

:charectarselect
cd gamedata
color 0f
cls
batbox /g 0 0
echo Select class:
echo.
echo %mage%
echo %worrior%
set /p classes=Class: 

if "%classes%" == "1" echo %mage%>pclass.gm
if "%classes%" == "2" echo %worrior%>pclass.gm
batbox /c 0x0f
goto login

:: ###############GAME##############

:game
color 0f
batbox /c 0x0f
cls
SET /A test=%RANDOM% * 3 / 32768 + 1
set /a m1=%random% * 10 / 32768 + 1
set /a mh=%random% * 20 / 32768 + 5
set /a rph=%random% * 20 / 32768 + 5
set /a pd=%random% * 15 / 32768 + 1
goto display

:: ###############DISPLAY##############

:display
color 0f
batbox /c 0x0f
cls
batbox /c 0xc9 /d "Health: %health%"
batbox /g 11 0 /c 0x9c /d "Strength: %strength%"
batbox /g 3 2 /c 0x89 /d "%test%"
goto mechanics

:: ###############MECHANICS##############

:mechanics
cls
set /a health-=%m1%
set /a mh-=%pd%
if %mh% lss 1 set /a health+=%rph% && goto game
if %health% lss 1 goto shop
pause >nul
goto game


:shop
cls
pause
```

I post the whole code now so yeah
Ok so idk where the problem is.. I have changed all the colors but i still get a grey background where i cant see the text with the `%health%` `%strength` and `%pclass%`

Comment: The posted code fragment hardly can dump the list of environment variables. Make sure [you've located the problem part](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @wOxxOm I dont really understand. What do you mean?

Comment: The output you have provided is a result of using the `set` command by itself. This occurs nowhere in the snippet of code that you have provided. Please provide more of your code.

Comment: he means: the Code, you showed us, is not able to produce the Output, you showed us.

Comment: @Stephan But whu tho?

Comment: @minefedtgamer because wrgl woms. (Sorry - couldn't resist) Could you repeat your last comment in english words please?

Comment: I assume he meant "why," as y and u are right next to each other on the keyboard.

Comment: @minefedtgamer - To reiterate, the output you have provided is a result of using the `set` command by itself. Since the code that you included doesn't have a `set` by itself, it is impossible to pinpoint the location of the incorrect line. Please include _all_ of your code in the question.

Comment: @SomethingDark Ok there you go

Comment: Hmm... I can't seem to duplicate your problem. I am, however, stuck in an infinite login loop.

Comment: same here. And still no Code, that would be able to show the variables. @minefedtgamer: remove `@echo off` to see, where it happens.

Comment: @SomethingDark Have you made a user?

Comment: Wait, it's not an infinite login loop; it just looks like one because the window title never changed from "Login" and the `cls` should be at the beginning of `:display` and not `:mechanics`. It is still an infinite loop, though, since the odds of `%health%` hitting 0 exactly is extremely small.

Comment: @SomethingDark Isn't there a command called "lss" or something like that?

Comment: @SomethingDark Ok so now it doesnt crash but i just get a grey screen. let me just update the post

Comment: @minefedtgamer - Please read my comments more carefully. _Again_, you don't see anything because you need to delete the `cls` command from the `:mechanics` section!